# Hard recurrence relationship

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I'm new to recurrence relations, and I'm inventing some exercises by myself in order to solve them. Considering this recurrence relation

$$
x_n = x_{n-1} - \lambda (x_{n-1} - 1)^2
$$

where $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Does this recurrence relationship has a solution for a generic point $x_1 = a>1$?

Comment: What do you mean by "have a solution"?

Comment: Expressing $x_n$ in terms of $n$

Comment: finding a closed form solution looks tough

Comment: Indeed :) that's why I've asked... even finding some seed $a>1$ for the recurrence such that $x_n \to 1$

Comment: You could try assuming $x_n=1+"\text{something}"$, which reduces it a bit.

Comment: For any $\lambda>0$ and any seed $1\le a\le1+1/\lambda$, $x_n\to1$.

Comment: Assuming what I mentioned above makes this problem equivalent to solving $$y_{n+1}=y_n-\lambda(y_n)^2$$

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I'd prefer to assume $1 < a \leq 1 + 1/ \lambda$, but can you explain me your reasoning? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If an explicit formula for $x_n$ existed, one could solve the recursion $z\to z-\lambda z^2$, which can be reduced to $z\to z^2+c$, which is a notoriously unsolvable case (keyword: Mandelbrot...).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the original question (an explicit formula for $x_n$) but to the request of the OP about the the behavior of the sequence $\{x_n\}$, and is too long for a comment.

Let $\lambda>0$ and $f(x)=x-\lambda(x-1)^2$. We have $f(1)=f(1+1/\lambda)=1$. If $a=1$ or $a=1+1/\lambda$, then $x_n=1$ for all $n>1$.

It is easy to check that $1<f(x)<x$ if $1<x<1+1/\lambda$. This implies that if $1<a<1+1/\lambda$, then $\{x_n\}$ is strictly decreasing and bounded below by $1$. Thus  $\{x_n\}$ converges, and the only possible limit is $1$.

It is also easy to see that if $a\notin[1,1+1/\lambda]$, then $x_n\to-\infty$.